# Error: "argument of type 'method' is not iterable" in loading a csv file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, typeerror

I am trying to read file in csv using panda. But the code is returning "argument of type 'method' is not iterable."

I tried the following code and I was expecting the panda to return a data Frame

The actual file called "WY.action.CR.load" has rows that looks like this:

64093911|5303477|CR|WY|124|APLN RECD|1905-05-19 00:00:00| || || || |
64093912|5303477|CR|WY|307|ROW GRANTED-ISSUED|1905-06-05 00:00:00||||||PERPETUAL;||

```
df_WY_action_CR_load = dbdir + '/Data/Raw/BLM_LR2000/NEW_FORMAT/INCR/2022_03_08/WY_20220306_CUST_ORDER2050/WY.action.CR.load'

df_WY_action_CR_load= pd.read_csv(df_WY_action_CR_load, delimiter="|",
                         names=['action_cd_id', 'case_id', 'system_id', 'blm_admin_st', 'act_cd', 'act_txt',
                                'act_dt', 'pending_flg', 'receipt_nr', 'doc_nr', 'pending_org',
                                'pend_org_decode', 'action_remark', 'all_land_flag'])
```

But I got an error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [129], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 df_WY_action_CR_load= pd.read_csv(df_WY_action_CR_load, delimiter="|",
      2                          names=['action_cd_id', 'case_id', 'system_id', 'blm_admin_st', 'act_cd', 'act_txt',
      3                                 'act_dt', 'pending_flg', 'receipt_nr', 'doc_nr', 'pending_org',
      4                                 'pend_org_decode', 'action_remark', 'all_land_flag'])

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py:311, in deprecate_nonkeyword_arguments.<locals>.decorate.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    305 if len(args) > num_allow_args:
    306     warnings.warn(
    307         msg.format(arguments=arguments),
    308         FutureWarning,
    309         stacklevel=stacklevel,
    310     )
--> 311 return func(*args, **kwargs)

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py:680, in read_csv(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, cache_dates, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, doublequote, escapechar, comment, encoding, encoding_errors, dialect, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, on_bad_lines, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map, float_precision, storage_options)
    665 kwds_defaults = _refine_defaults_read(
    666     dialect,
    667     delimiter,
   (...)
    676     defaults={"delimiter": ","},
    677 )
    678 kwds.update(kwds_defaults)
--> 680 return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py:575, in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    572 _validate_names(kwds.get("names", None))
    574 # Create the parser.
--> 575 parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
    577 if chunksize or iterator:
    578     return parser

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py:933, in TextFileReader.__init__(self, f, engine, **kwds)
    930     self.options["has_index_names"] = kwds["has_index_names"]
    932 self.handles: IOHandles | None = None
--> 933 self._engine = self._make_engine(f, self.engine)

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py:1217, in TextFileReader._make_engine(self, f, engine)
   1213     mode = "rb"
   1214 # error: No overload variant of "get_handle" matches argument types
   1215 # "Union[str, PathLike[str], ReadCsvBuffer[bytes], ReadCsvBuffer[str]]"
   1216 # , "str", "bool", "Any", "Any", "Any", "Any", "Any"
-> 1217 self.handles = get_handle(  # type: ignore[call-overload]
   1218     f,
   1219     mode,
   1220     encoding=self.options.get("encoding", None),
   1221     compression=self.options.get("compression", None),
   1222     memory_map=self.options.get("memory_map", False),
   1223     is_text=is_text,
   1224     errors=self.options.get("encoding_errors", "strict"),
   1225     storage_options=self.options.get("storage_options", None),
   1226 )
   1227 assert self.handles is not None
   1228 f = self.handles.handle

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/common.py:661, in get_handle(path_or_buf, mode, encoding, compression, memory_map, is_text, errors, storage_options)
    658 encoding = encoding or "utf-8"
    660 # read_csv does not know whether the buffer is opened in binary/text mode
--> 661 if _is_binary_mode(path_or_buf, mode) and "b" not in mode:
    662     mode += "b"
    664 # validate encoding and errors

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/common.py:1128, in _is_binary_mode(handle, mode)
   1125 if issubclass(type(handle), text_classes):
   1126     return False
-> 1128 return isinstance(handle, _get_binary_io_classes()) or "b" in getattr(
   1129     handle, "mode", mode
   1130 )

TypeError: argument of type 'method' is not iterable
```

Is there something I am not doing right?

Comment: Is the first argument (`df_WY_action_CR_load`) a string path to the filename, or a file object?

Comment: `df_WY_action_CR_load` is a function. You need to call it with `()`.

Comment: Or replace that with the actual variable that contains the filename you want to read.

Comment: @nofinator its a path to the file name. I update my question to include the path

Comment: @SangeenKhan Thanks. That looks better though. When I run a similar version of that code, I'm not getting that error. Are you still getting a TypeError?

Comment: @nofinator. I ran this code for two other files. It worked perfectly fine with those two. But I am getting error with this one file, an I am unable to figure out.

Comment: @Barmar. Do you mean I write print(df_WY_action_CR_load)?

Comment: No, `pd.read_csv(df_WY_action_CR_load(), ...`

Comment: But now I don't think that's right. The first argument of `read_csv()` isn't supposed to be an iterable, so I don't think the error is coming from there. Please post the full traceback.

Comment: Thanks @Barmer! I tried, it returned 
TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable

Comment: @barmer the file path looks like this:
df_WY_action_CR_load = dbdir + '/Data/Raw/BLM_LR2000/NEW_FORMAT/INCR/2022_03_08/WY_20220306_CUST_ORDER2050/WY.action.CR.load'

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the entire error message. This should show which line of code caused the error.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I just updated my question

Comment: What is the value of `dbdir`? Is it a string or is it a `Path`? If it is a string, I don't see how it can cause this error.

Comment: On a side note, you are using the same variable for two different purposes. First you assign `df_WY_action_CR_load` to the path of a file, then you assign it to a dataframe. I recommend using two separate variable names to avoid confusion and potential bugs.

Comment: It looks to me like you're running this in a Jupyter notebook or similar, with the same `df_WY_action_CR_load` variable having different meanings in different cells. This will lead to reproducibility issues.  Please make sure the assignment-to-string immediately precedes the use-as-filepath and is in the same cell.  For good measure, assign `dbdir` in that cell as well, and print `df_WY_action_CR_load` just before the call to `pd.read_csv()`.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice thank you for your suggestion! dbdir is a string. I changed the name of the data frame. but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Will you add a `print()` statement to see the value of the first argument to `read_csv()`?

Comment: @SarahMesser Thank you so much! your suggestion worked!